# Snapping vertex with edge slide but cannot be parallel to snapped vertex

Tags: snapping

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Actually, I've done it with a boolean method.

[image]

[image]

But is there any other method that is faster than what I did?
Some kind of special tool, I don't know much about the tools in this blender software. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the general case where you're looking for closest point to an arbitrary vertex from an arbitrarily rotated edge I'm not aware of a faster method, and you may have to use TinyCad to do some edge intersection projection - but, that said, here is my best attempt to make it quicker:

Starting from this point and attempting to make the highlighted vertex slide along its edge and intersect with the notional plane extending along the Y axis from the floating edge behind it:

[image: starting point]

Extrude a temporary face from the rear edge until it intersects the target edge:

[image: extrude temporary face]

Set snapping options to Face snap:

[image: snapping options]

Perform a vertex slide on the target vertex and snap to the face:

[image: Snap target vertex to face]

Delete the temporary construction geometry, and confirm that the vertex is now in the intended position:

[[image: Final state, intended result hopefully5]

Obviously this is several steps, so it may take quite a while for many vertices, but if all of the snap target is a single section you could probably extrude it all at once, and possibly then separate the new geometry to a separate object to make it easier to delete later.  Then it's just a matter of selecting each vertex or group of vertices in turn.  Vertex slide will work on multiple, but snap will typically fail on groups and does in this example, so you need to select and snap move them individually.

Comment: The geometry I gave is not a flat plane. there are lots of curves but I want to give it an aligned loop cut.
I give you another [geometry](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BZVbWa4IMXKxhyDlwGkU8NAOxaJmZVLs/view?usp=sharing), similar to the image above but simpler.

Comment: What I'm actually trying to do is make a simple cube with a bevel on each corner and has a convex plane, but with a good topology so I can subdivide the surface if needed. It would be more helpful for me if you had a much better method. Thank you.

Comment: Thankyou for the blend file, that is helpful.  You should edit it into the question so anyone else can use it to make a better answer.  Apologies for the unhelpful answer myself, I couldn't tell curvature from the original images - yes, with curved surfaces like that one it is much more complicated.  You can extrude edges and construct intersections that way but it sounds like the boolean method may be faster or similar in that case.  I will try and edit the answer later to show how extruding an edge and then snapping to the resulting face works, although it's more steps than is convenient.

Comment: This is my best effort.  If it still isn't quite what you were looking for then I think it's safe to say I don't have an answer :)